# Filter a list, according to the result of another query

Tags: apache-pig

I am in this scenario. I have a variable `data` which contains a list of value in this format:

```
data:(id:int, value:float)
```

Then I have another variable containing some metadata:

```
m:(id:int, var1:int, var2:int)
```

What I want to do is:

1. Filter `m` so as to take the list of `id` which satisfy some condition on the metadata
2. Filter `data`, keeping only the tuples which `id` is in the result set of the first query.

I.e. something like:

```
wanted_metadata = filter m by CONDITION
wanted_ids = foreach wanted_metadata generate id
wanted_data = filter data by id IS INCLUDED IN wanted_ids
```

For the time being, I managed to do that using the JOIN operator, but I would prefer to use some "membership check" operator.

Could you help me?

Comment: I think that an inner join is exactly what you should be using.  Just  look at [this graph](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp).    Your usage of join here __is__ a membership check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is small enough to fit into RAM, than use [replicated join](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref1.html#Replicated+Joins), which is map side join, which is implemented as a membership check.